# How to convert Icon into a base64 string?

Tags: c#, base64

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(_path);
```

How do I convert the above `icon` into a base64 string in C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to get the raw bytes of the icon:

```
var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(_path);
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    icon.Save(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Then you can convert the bytes to a base64 string:

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. I was using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`.